# What does "stream out" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "stream out" mean in the following?

> In addition to that Musk must also **stream out** revenue channels and profit goals. If these milestones are met, Musk’s total equity earnings would zoom to $55 billion by 2028 hoping that Tesla will not float any additional shares.

[Source](https://www.ibtimes.com/elon-musk-net-worth-20b-how-tesla-ceo-spending-it-2803897).

Comment: It's certainly not a well-known idiomatic usage (for all I know, your cited writer is the only one who's ever used it. But it's fairly obvious to me what he means - *Musk must ensure his revenue channels and profit goals **come on stream** (start operating as planned)*. But really I think he's getting a bit carried away with his essentially "creative" usage. Terms like ***reify, actualise, cause to materialise*** are effectively synonymous, but I don't much like any of them being *simultaneously* applied to "revenue channels and profit goals" (they're not the same ***kind*** of thing).

Comment: Better to apply different verbs to the two things Musk needs to deal with. He must ***roll out / implement*** his revenue-earning channels, and ***meet / reach*** his profit goals.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: He may also (or instead) be trying to say Musk needs to draw up "project progress" charts with revenue targets at various points. But I don't think Musk is too concerned about that kind of "pension fund manager's" approach. Short-term profitability isn't a big factor in his thinking.